# extract method in raster package

Tags: extract, raster, terra

I am practicing ensemble sdm methods using SABAP2 records for a species and doing modeling, I am stuck at the point of joining the species point data with the wordclim data using the extract method.
I loaded all these packages:

```
library (sp)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library (raster)
library(terra)
```

Here is the code:

```
data_SABAP2 <- cbind(recs_SABAP2, raster::extract (x = climSABAP2, data.frame (recs_SABAP2 [,c('decimalLongitude','decimalLatitude')])))
```

output:

```
data_SABAP2 <- cbind(recs_SABAP2, raster::extract(x = climSABAP2, y = data.frame(recs_SABAP2[,c('decimalLongitude','decimalLatitude')]))) 

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "data.frame"’
```

while trying this

```
library(conflicted)
```

I get the results:

```
Error in library(conflicted): there is no package called ‘conflicted’
```

I am not sure as to what am doing wrong.

To continue running the code:

```
data_SABAP2 <- cbind(recs_SABAP2, raster::extract(x = climSABAP2, y = data.frame(recs_SABAP2[,c('decimalLongitude','decimalLatitude')]))) 
final_SABAP2 <- data_SABAP2[,c("decimalLongitude","decimalLatitude", "species", "bio2", "bio8", "bio9", "bio15", "bio18", "bio19")]
final_SABAP2$species <-1
head(final_SABAP2)
```